# Power Series $(\sin(z))^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Power Series $(\sin(z))^2$ for complex $z$:

Knowing that $\sin(z) = \sum [(-1)^n z^{2n+1}] /[(2n+1)!] $. If I were to square it, then this is equivalent to multiplying the two series together $\sin(z) \times \sin(z)$. As such, the term $c_n$ can be written as ($a_k, b_k$ terms in the two multiplied series):

$$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)! (2n-2k+1)!}$$

Thus can I write the power series expansion as:

$$(\sin(z))^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)! (2n-2k+1)!} z^{2n+1}$$

Please let me know if this would be an appropriate representation

Comment: it's much easier to use $2\sin^2 z=1-\cos 2z$ and derive the Taylor series from there

Comment: It looks like you lost the power of $(-1)^{n-k}$ coming from the second copy of the sine function, although I might not have checked carefully. This greatly simplifies the sign since $(-1)^n$ pulls out. You can also use combinatorial identities to simplify the inside. Or use @Conrad's trick.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2396742/42969

Comment: Or check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3203279/42969

Comment: Can I close a question? I only see here an option to delete.